# Edit a particular string in a file based on another file

Tags: xargs, for

Hello I have a file called users. In that file i have a list of users for example

```
user1
user2
user3
```

Now i have another file called searches where there is a specific string called owner = user for example

```
owner = user1
random text
random text
owner = user15
random text 
random text 
owner = user2
```

so is it possible to find all the users based on the users file and rename those users to user@domain.com ? for example

```
owner = user1@domain.com
random text
random text
owner = user15
random text 
random text 
owner = user2@domain.com
```

i got some bits and pieces working using the ack command and the cat command but i am new to programming so i cant get a proper output. What i figured out is below but it does not really do what i need. any help is highly appreciated.

```
cat users | xargs -i sed 's/{}/moo/' searches
```

Comment: Removing the completely unrelated [tag:loop-device]. Please make sure you read the tag descriptions before using a tag. While the approach you're sketching is certainly viable, we're not really a "free code" service! If I had a recommendation for how to approach this class of problem, it would probably not entail learning shell scripting (as you're currently proposing), but learning a more universally useful language such as Python. This specific problem is a bit easier in Python, and if you're new to programming, that might be the more useful thing to learn.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try awk:

```
awk 'NR == FNR {SRCH[$1]; next} $NF in SRCH {$NF = $NF "@domain.com"} 1'   users searches
owner = user1@domain.com
random text
random text
owner = user15
random text 
random text 
owner = user2@domain.com
```

It adds the addendum if user found in `users` file.

Comment: Ma man... This is pure gold.  this is exactly what i was trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Use `awk`:

```
awk '
  NR==FNR{users[$0]=$0"@domain.com"}
  NR>FNR && $1 == "owner" && $3 in users { $3=users[$3]; }
  NR>FNR
' users searches
```

To edit file directly, append `> searches.tmp && mv searches.tmp searches`

Comment: hello, thanks for replying. i am getting a xargs: illegal option -- a i tried in /bin/bash as well. still the same error.

Comment: probably `-a` is GNU find ...

Comment: This opens and writes the "searches" file umpteen times, even is a user is not found at all.

Comment: Changed answer completely to use `awk`.